# Facebook force refresh or pull of data

Tags: jquery, facebook, refresh, facebook-comments

I ma using the Facebook comment plugin

```
$('.fb-comments').attr('data-href', window.location.href);

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=694645587257406&version=v2.4";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In my template I have

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Because my data in is an modal window the issue I am having is while the url does update the comments do not update until I hit refresh. Is there a way for for a refresh when the href changes?.

I am using modal windows so the page never actually refreshes. Which is a nice effect I would like to retain.

Comment: Why don't make an ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [`FB.XFBML.parse()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) might be what you're looking for. That should re-render your comments plugin!